# Gulp: Error: Unhandled “error” event. (1) when phpunit test fails

Tags: javascript, gulp, phpunit

I am trying to autorun phpunit using gulp. When phpunit fails a test I see the following error in terminal (all passed tests do not cause the error):

```
FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.

events.js:188
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Unhandled "error" event. (1)
    at Domain.emit (events.js:186:19)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:181:14)
    at Stream.onerror (/var/www/html/wptest2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:640:52)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at next (/var/www/html/wptest2/node_modules/map-stream/index.js:74:19)
    at /var/www/html/wptest2/node_modules/map-stream/index.js:84:7
    at /var/www/html/wptest2/node_modules/gulp-phpunit/index.js:341:17
    at /var/www/html/wptest2/node_modules/shelljs/src/exec.js:204:9
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:282:5)
```

Gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect-php'),
    gulpPhpunit = require('gulp-phpunit');

gulp.task('gulpPhpunit', function(done) {
  var options = {debug: false};
  gulp.src('phpunit.xml')
      .pipe(gulpPhpunit('./vendor/bin/phpunit', options));

  done();
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.series('gulpPhpunit'));
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Try changing it to: `.pipe(gulpPhpunit('./vendor/bin/phpunit', options).on('error', function(){ console.log('error');}));`

Comment: Or the [NPM documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-phpunit) shows that you can pass in a callback after the options, that may be enough